# check if a string only contains specified characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to check that a string only contains letters, `a-zA-Z`, numbers `0-9`, and operators `(+=-*/^)`

For example, the following expression would be permissible: `3 + 5(x^2)`

For example, the following expression would **not** be permissible: `3 $+ 5(x^2)`

Would I use the matches function to do this?

I tried:

```
// contains only operators, numbers, or letters
if(!exp.matches("[(+=-*/^)a-zA-Z0-9]")) { 
    return false;
}
```

I also tried escaping the asterisk, but it didn't work.

Comment: The dash between `=` and `*` needs to come at the end of character class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Or be escaped, which is likely less error-prone for future edits of the regex.

Comment: thanks you very much!

Comment: [Check that the input only contains certain characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631653/check-that-the-input-only-contains-certain-characters) only answers the current question in part, mainly, put all the chars into a character class and use `String#matches()`. There are 2 issues in this question that makes it a different one: 1) here, no quantifiers has been used, 2) here,  the `-` was misplaced and caused a serious issue. Hence, reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have escaped `-` or put it at the start/end of the character class, else it creates a *range*. Note that `[=-*]` range is *invalid*:

[image]

Also, you need a quantifier, `+` to match 1 or more chars, `*` to match 0 or more.

Use

```
if(!exp.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9+=*/^()-]+")) { 
        return false;
}
```

If you do not need to match `(` and `)`, remove them from the character class.

Also, since the `String#matches()` requires a full string match, no anchors at the start and end of the regular expression are necessary.

Comment: And make sure not to put `^` first, because that has special meaning too, like `-` does if not first or last.

Comment: @Andreas: The character class is not a *negated* one, it is positive. I.e. the pattern should only match a valid pattern. If the string does not match the pattern, false is returned.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know, that's why I said to make sure *not* to put it first, because that would *accidentally* change the character class to a negative.